# How to associate Office 365 subscription to Azure AD directory

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

**Given situation**

I have two Azure AD directories in one Azure portal tenant.

1. AD_1 - A directory that got automatically created when signed up for Azure cloud the first time
2. AD_2 - A directory that I have manually created for managing a different set of users.

I also have an office365 account, that got created using the same Azure account. In it first I purchased a subscription.

- SUBSCRIPTION_1 - only office apps. The licenses are attached to users in AD_1

Later I purchased another subscription purely for non-office products for different set of users.

- SUBSCRIPTION_2 - exchange, yammer etc apps - A new subscription.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to associate SUBSCRIPTION_2 to only users in directory AD_2?
- If above is YES, how to do?

*Disclaimer*: *I am a noob to whole Azure AD, Office 365, for that matter Microsoft products. Please forgive my naivety.*

Comment: I don't believe this question fits StackOverflow, but you may want to check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory) and [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-use-existing-office-365-account-azure-subscription). Will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter the originating subscription access to services or apps only depends on licenses. So just navigate to Office 365 Portal >  Administration  > Users > Active, there select a user and assign the appropriate license, no matter from which AD user comes from, in fact it is also possible to assign licenses to users created in a local AD that is synchronized to Azure AD (administration privileges are needed for this procedure)